# Exactly once in kafka streams- not working

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, exactly-once

I am testing exactly once in kafka streams by shutting down multiple brokers.
But when i restart the brokers same message is getting produced multiple times on outbound topic.
I am using confluent version 6.1.0
Setting processing guarantee to exactly once beta
acks is set to all

Can any one please help me understand if i am missing any configurations?